Probability of opponents drawing cards greater than X and Y in a multiplayer game
In order to create a bot for a multiplayer card game called "Mexican Tarot", I'm trying to solve a probability problem involving card draws.
Here's the context: In this game, we play with a Tarot deck consisting of 22 cards (from 0 to 21). Every player draws the same number of cards (which varies each turn, from 5 to 1). Before each turn, every player bets on the number of "rounds" they think they can win. Winning a round means having the highest card. After all announcements, players play cards one by one; whoever has the highest card wins the round. If you win fewer or more rounds than you announced, you lose a life.
(As this game is a little bit more complex, I am linking a French page with the rules here, but the explanation above will be sufficient for the following problem)
To give an example, I already calculated the probability for a turn with 1 card: The bot has a known card X (between 0 and 21), and the 3 other opponents each have one unknown card. The probability of winning the round (i.e., saying "I bet 1 round") is the probability that the bot's card is the highest among the other players. This is the probability that the 3 other opponents' cards are lower than X, which is given by $\frac{\binom{X}{3} \times \binom{21-X}{0}}{\binom{21}{3}}$ (with $\binom{n}{k}$ being the combination formula, "k out of n").
Conversely, winning while betting "0 rounds" is the probability that at least one other player has a card higher than X, which is 1 - P(all 3 other cards are lower than X) = $1 - \frac{\binom{X}{3} \times \binom{21-X}{0}}{\binom{21}{3}}$.
I now want to calculate probabilities with 2 cards in hand. Specifically, I'm interested in calculating the probability of winning while betting 0 rounds, which is that, among the 6 cards drawn by my three opponents (each player draws 2 cards), at least one card is greater than X (my lowest card) and at least another is greater than Y (my highest card).
I'm struggling to figure out how to combine these probabilities properly. Does anyone have any insights or suggestions on how to approach this problem? And maybe a generic version that's work for 3, 4 and 5 cards? Feel free to ask for any additional details or explanations.
Thanks in advance!

Not sure I follow.  If four of us each have the same number of cards, the deal being selected uniformly at random from the deck,  then the probability that a given player has the highest card is $\frac 14$.  Nobody has an advantage.

More seriously, you seem to be ignoring strategy.  If I, the first player, hold two cards, say $16, 18$, I might choose to play the $16$ thinking it unlikely that anyone will happen to have the $17$ (and wanting to save the $18$ for a later round.  The rules are quite vague so I'm not sure how strategy plays out in this game.

When each player draws $1$ card, no player makes any decisions. When each player draws $2$ cards, the players have to decide the order in which to play their cards. You have to prescribe a method for choosing play order before you compute win probabilities in this case

I'm voluntarily ignoring all the strategy aspects and the fact that you'll probably play after/before opponents. I just want to calculate a 'greedy' probability, which in my case corresponds to the probability of an existing winning scenario, giving the card of the bot.

Consider the eight cards dealt out, and rank them #1 through #8 from highest to lowest.  You will be forced to take one round if either of the following is true:

You are dealt the highest card and any of the other seven cards.
You are dealt the second-highest and third-highest cards.

In all other cases, there exists a scenario where you take no rounds.
Suppose you know the cards $X$ and $Y$ you are dealt, where $X > Y$.  We want to know the probability, given $X$ and $Y$, that Case 1 is true or that Case 2 is true (note that these are mutually exclusive.)  There are 20 other cards in play, of which 6 have been dealt out, so there are $N = \binom{20}{6} = 38760$ possibilities for the other six cards in play.  So the question boils down to figuring out how many other permutations correspond to each of the two cases above.
Case 1
Of the 20 other cards, $X - 1$ are lower than $X$ (note that this set does not include card $Y < X$, whose location is known.)  So the number of ways that the six cards can be selected from the 20 such that Case 1 is satisfied is
$N_1 = \binom{X - 1}{6}.$
Case 2
Out of the 20 remaining cards, there are $21 - X$ cards higher than $X$, and $Y$ cards lower than $Y$.  The number of ways to select six cards out of the 20 such that one is from this first set and and the other five are from the second set is then $N_2 = (21 - X) \binom{Y}{5}.$
Combining these, the overall probability that the cards are dealt in such a way that you cannot avoid taking a round is then $\frac{N_1 + N_2}{N}$, or
$$
P = \frac{1}{38760} \left[ \binom{X-1}{6} + (21 - X) \binom{Y}{5}\right].
$$
A heatmap of these probabilities is shown below.

In principle one could extend this logic for higher numbers of cards.  For example, if each player has three cards you'd have to consider four distinct cases where you are forced to take at least one round:

You have the highest card
You have the second- and third-highest cards
You have the second-, fourth-, and fifth-highest cards
You have the third-, fourth-, and fifth-highest cards

This would get increasingly tedious as the number of cards increases, but would be doable in principle.

@LeMagicienAnnonyme I think I've actually answered your problem now.  See the completely revised version.

Thank you for your answer and great explanation! Have a great day!

@LeMagicienAnnonyme:  Please note the correction to my final formula for the probability;  I accidentally had $\binom{19}{6}$ in the denominator instead of $\binom{20}{6}$.

We'll consider the broader problem of minimizing the number of tricks the player is forced to take, assuming the remaining cards are dealt uniformly at random to the opponents, but otherwise making the most optimistic assumptions as to the opponent's plays.
Brute force
If you are only doing one problem of this size at a time, it's computationally feasible to simply enumerate all $\binom{22 - h}{3h}$ possible sets of cards dealt to the other players. A slight optimization would be to relabel the cards according to how many of your own cards they are higher than, in which case you have at most $h + 1$ multichoose $3h$ = $\binom{4h}{3h}$ distinguishable hands, which you would weight using the multivariate hypergeometric distribution.
Dynamic programming
Let's try expressing the process of finding the minimum number of tricks taken in terms of a "single pass" over the values of the cards in descending order:

Iterate over the card values from highest to lowest.
If nobody has that card, skip it.
If the card is one of the first (i.e highest) $h$ belonging to an opponent, reserve it. Optimistically, these will all be played during separate tricks.
If the card is one of the $h$ belonging to the player, match it up with the highest opponent card that was reserved, forming a trick that the player was not forced to take. Since this is higher than any future player cards, this also eliminates the greatest possible liability on the player side. Conversely, if there is no available reserved opponent card, the player is forced to take that trick.

It turns out that any "single-pass" evaluation like this can be used to produce an algorithm that is polynomial-time in both hand and deck size via dynamic programming (or if you prefer, "recurrence relations") by expressing the solution to the problem in terms of subproblems of smaller decks and hands. This is implemented in my Icepool Python probability package.
Fool high or low
If the Fool (0) can be treated as both high and low, and we optimistically assume that it is high when someone else plays it and low when we play it, then we can conditionally change the value of the Fool to 22 when it is not in the player's hand.
Putting it together
from icepool import MultisetEvaluator, Order, Deck

class MexicanTarotEvaluator(MultisetEvaluator):
    def next_state(self, state, outcome, player, opposition):
        # tricks: Tricks forced to be taken by player.
        # saved: Higher cards from opposition not yet paired.
        tricks, saved = state or (0, 0)
        # Player cards that can be paired with equal or higher opposition
        # cards are non-tricks.
        new_non_tricks = min(player, saved + opposition)
        # Any remaining player cards are tricks.
        new_tricks = player - new_non_tricks
        return tricks + new_tricks, saved + opposition - new_non_tricks
        
    def order(self):
        return Order.Descending
        
    def final_outcome(self, final_state):
        return final_state[0]
        
mexican_tarot_evaluator = MexicanTarotEvaluator()
full_deck = Deck(range(22))

def mexican_tarot(hand, players):
    # Remove player hand from the remaining cards.
    deck = full_deck - hand
    # Fool is optimistically treated as 22 if not in player hand.
    deck = deck.map({0: 22})
    opponent = deck.deal(len(hand) * (players - 1))
    return mexican_tarot_evaluator(hand, opponent)
    
output(mexican_tarot([15, 19, 20, 21], 4))

This is integrated into Icepool more concisely as maximum_match_highest():
from icepool import Deck, Pool

full_deck = Deck(range(22))

def mexican_tarot(hand, players):
    # Remove player hand from the remaining cards.
    deck = full_deck - hand
    # Fool is optimistically treated as 22 if not in player hand.
    deck = deck.map({0: 22})
    opponent = deck.deal(len(hand) * (players - 1))
    return Pool(hand).maximum_match_highest('<=', opponent, keep='unmatched').count()
    
output(mexican_tarot([15, 19, 20, 21], 4))

You can try this in your browser here. API subject to change.
